# Dúvida - Enviar Ajax no Clique do Checkbox (Perfomance, Network)

Tags: ajax, asp.net, mvc

Tenho uma tabela em uma view, que lista os módulos, com cada módulo e cada usuário, e um checkbox que indica se o usuário tem ou não acesso ao módulo, e quero na ação de mudar o checkbox fazer o seguinte ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#activelist').change(function () {
    var valor = 0;
    if ($("#activelist").is(":checked")){
    valor = 1;
    } 
    var usuario = $(this).data("usuario");
    var cod_modulo = $(this).data("cod_modulo");
    var url = "Pessoa/Acesso";
    $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: url,
                data: { 'usuario': usuario, 'cod_modulo' : cod_modulo, 'acesso' : valor },
                dataType: 'html',
                success: function () {
                    alert("Sucesso!")
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert('Error loading Ajax!');
                }
            });
       });
  });
```

Essa url `Pessoa/Acesso` é uma **action** de um *controller* que vai fazer o update no BD, passando como parâmetros o *usuário*, *cod_modulo* e o *acesso* que se o checkbox estiver checado é 1, se não 0.

Então cada vez que eu clicar no checkbox, ele vai enviar um update pro banco via **POST** por **AJAX**..

Mas agora fiquei na dúvida, fazer isso vai consumir muito network? Pode ficar lento? Performance? Devo atualizar a cada vez que o usuário clicar no checkbox?

Comment: acredito que a pergunta mais apropriada seria *"devo atualizar a cada vez que o usuário clicar no checkbox"*? tem outros campos nessa tela? não poderia usar um botão de atualizar?

Comment: Cara, agora estou no trabalho e o código está no meu notebook pessoal... mas basicamente é uma tabela, com o código e nome do módulo, nome do usuário e o checkbox se ele tem permissão ou não... Pensei em fazer algo do tipo ele marcar todos checkbox e aí clicar no salvar e salvar todos... porém, não sei como faço para passar essa lista de usuários pro meu controller... Eu sei que com o código ficaria mais fácil de me ajudar, assim que conseguir eu posto ele aqui

Comment: Ai pensei nessa alternativa por **ajax**, mas aí fiquei em dúvida em questão de performance/network